# Django - how to export and import user data for database migration?

Tags: django, dumpdata

I am moving my website to another cloud server for delpoying, so I have to export all the user information (account name, password, accounts.profile from the existing database, then import to the new website hosted by the new server.

I have tried to export user data using default: python manage.py dumpdata > users.json
the users.json looks like:

[{"model": "accounts.profile", "pk": 1, "fields": {"user": 2, "telephone": "0755-25187181", "company_name": "watchtech"}}, {"model": "accounts.profile", "pk": 2, "fields": {"user": 3, "telephone": "18696511023", "company_name": "King's Machinery"}},....}}]

I noticed there is no password information exported. when I use "python manage.py loaddata user.json", how to ensure it also loads the password of users, so that users can login the new website?

**UPDATE - please note that I have applied "accounts.profile" model in addition to the default user model, to include more fields of user information.**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver


class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    telephone = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    company_name = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
```

this is the CMD I used to export both the user and order data from the original database, which result in two json files.

```
source myvenv/bin/activate; python3.6 manage.py dumpdata accounts>DB_backup/user_backup.json
source myvenv/bin/activate; python3.6 manage.py dumpdata OnlinePricing>DB_backup/order_backup.json
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a real database dump using your database management tools.

`dumpdata` and `loaddata` are not intended to move a complete website.

The posted part of your dump is just the `accounts.profile` model data. The user data (username, password hash, email, ...) belong to another model in your application and therefore are somewhere later in your `users.json`.

Comment: thank you for your reply. I have updated my problem statement incl. part of the codes. Could you advise how to export full user data?